# PHP: Using GOTO to skip rendering of HTML

Tags: php

Apologies if this has been asked somewhere else. I did search, but it's a bite of a niche question I think.

I currently use a simple bit of GOTO logic to skip the rendering of certain HTML elements, based on a users permissions. I want to know if there is anything fundamentally wrong with this approach and if so, what is the preferred alternative?

One of the main reasons I'm asking, is I'm slowly migrating my existing code to a more MVC approach, and I'm not sure GOTO is particularly compatible with MVC.

Many thanks for any answers.

For example:

```
<?php
$isUserAdmin = 0;
?>

<html>
<?php if(!$isUserAdmin) {goto notAdmin;} ?>
<a href="/admin.php">Admin Control Panel</a>
<?php notAdmin:  ?>
<a href="/vieworders.php">View Orders</a>
</html>
```

P.S - On pages I want to explicitly restrict, there is an actual explicit check which will redirect them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `goto` is something that is generally not advised, as it can cause what is called spaghetti code. Spaghetti code is where `goto` statements send you all over the source code instead of running from top to bottom through the code, as is expected, especially for non OOP interpreted code.

In your specific case, you can simply use an `if` statement.

```
<?php if ($isUserAdmin): ?>
<a href="/admin.php">Admin Control Panel</a>
<?php endif; ?>
<a href="/vieworders.php">View Orders</a>
```

Comment: Completely makes sense, thankyou. Is this approach generally accepted in a MVC model? Because the if statement would have to be placed in the View.

Many thanks!

Comment: In my experience, yes. For example, Laravel uses this kind of approach to, for example, show either a login or logout button on the main menu depending on if the user has logged in.

Comment: Gotcha, all makes sense to me - I'll start migrating to this approach. Thank you :).